# React Native open file from iCloud "Files" app not working

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a react native app that allows users to share their content by creating a zip file (I use a different extension, .ssc but it's really just a zip file).  The zip file can then be opened by another user with the app and the zip is processed and the data is imported.  This functionality works great if I open the file from an email or the dropbox app but when I store it in `iCloud Drive` and open it from the `Files` app on iOS, it opens the app but doesn't import the zip file into the `/Documents/Inbox` folder.

Any idea why the file is not being copied into the `/Documents/Inbox` when it's opened from the `Files` app?